# how can i resolve problem with strings in solidity?

Tags: solidity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe0Ve.png)

I'm getting issue with the data-type in Solidity v0.5.0,it shows the following message 
'Data locoation must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but was not given.'

Answer (score 0):

With 0.5.0 you need to explicitly mention what type of variables are they. Replace the parameter as `string memory newName` and `string memory` and that should resolve the code and compile file.